# Best practice to map and filter a collection of object in java using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a List of custom entities from which i want to valuate a field using a method,
and that i want to filter next. I'm fairly new to java streams,
and i don't know if it's better to use map and filters, or to use a more traditional `forEach`.
Here is my first attempt:

```
public List<Restaurant> findRestaurantsWithin(Double latitude, Double longitude, Integer radius) {
    log.info("Searching restaurants {} km to point {} lat., {} long.", radius, latitude, longitude);

    List<Restaurant> restaurants = this.restaurantRepository.findAll();

    restaurants.forEach(restaurant ->
        {
            if (restaurant.getLatitude() != null) {
                restaurant.setDistance(
                        this.getDistance(Double.parseDouble(restaurant.getLatitude()),
                                Double.parseDouble(restaurant.getLongitude()), latitude, longitude)
                );
            }
        }
    );

    return restaurants.stream()
            .filter(restaurant -> restaurant.getDistance() <= radius)
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Restaurant::getDistance))
            .skip(size * page - 1)
            .limit(size)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And here is the second :

```java
return this.restaurantRepository.findAll().stream()
                .filter(restaurant ->
                {
                    if (restaurant.getLatitude() != null) {
                        Double distance = this.getDistance(Double.parseDouble(restaurant.getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(restaurant.getLongitude()), latitude, longitude);
                        if (distance <= radius) {
                            restaurant.setDistance(distance);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                })
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Restaurant::getDistance))
                .skip(size * page - 1)
                .limit(size)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

On the second one i should probably use a `.map` first, but i'm not sure that there will be a difference in performance. Is there a better practice or more elegant way to get that ?
Thanks !

Comment: Is restaurantRepository a JpaRepository interface of Spring Data JPA ?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention it, cause here i thought it doesn't matter, but yes it is.

Comment: Don't you think, instead of `findAll` + `filter`, you should just `findFiltered`?

Comment: Then let the DB do the work it's supposed to do. Why filter potentially a few million entries in you're software when the DB is designed to do that much faster?

Comment: It matters. It's not a good practice to fetch everything from the DB and then make filtering because you get big latency fetching data you eventually won't need. Let the DBMS filter the data for you by telling JPA your criteria.

Comment: @NickDelta I know it would be better from the db, but to make it short, let's just assume that i can't do it from the db. There will not be many recordings anyway, and it's more for a stream training purpose.

Comment: The stream only approach is much better. Only thing I would change is to create a method which does what you are currently doing inside you're filter method. Also you may wants check out the `peek` method which allows you to execute any kind of operation with the current object being processed in the stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that `Restaunt::setDistance` is the big code smell here. Each restaurant is capable of holding property which says how far away it is from some other arbitrary point. We don't know where or what that point is, or when it was set. It's not a true property of a restaurant, it's just a hack.

Side effects and functional programming in general do not really mix well either, which is another reason both of your examples might seem clunky to you.

Here's how I'd do it, with a general purpose `Pair` class (there are many but the exact implementation shouldn't matter. Java FX was removed in I think Java 11, but if you're using a version of Java before that, `javafx.util.Pair` requires no dependencies)

```
return restaurantRepository.findAll().stream()
    .filter(restaurant -> restaurant.getLatitude() != null)
    .map(restaurant -> new Pair<>(restaurant, this.getDistance(/*blah blah*/)))
    .filter(resAndDistance -> resAndDistance.getValue() <= radius)       
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Pair::getValue))
    .skip(size * page - 1)
    .limit(size)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i understand what you say about the distance field. I have annotated it @Transient because it's not a true property, you are entirely right. I will try it your way ! Thanks !